# Adding a Border to Material Icons in Android

Tags: android, material-design

I want to use a white colored icon, but the problem is that the background is sometimes too light for it to be seen clearly. How do I add borders to in-house android icons?

Comment: Maybe editing them?

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can't add borders "on the go" because you can't use svg icons directly.

If you're using svg icons, look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) which allows you to convert an svg icon in png directly on the api. You'll still need to edit your svg icon.

If you're using png icons, then you need to edit them separately to add your borders.

Comment: Photoshop ? Illustrator ? I don't know, use the one you feel good with.